# could not find host matching read preferences in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a new collection in a new database on the sharded environment.

I am getting the following error while `coll.insertMany(list)`.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: 
Command failed with error 133: 'unable to target write op for collection dbname.collection:: caused by :: 
FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: Could not confirm non-existence of database "dbname" due to inability to query the config server primary :: caused by :: 
FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" } for set csReplSet' on server ip:27017. 
The full response is { "ok" : 0, "code" : 133, "errmsg" : "unable to target write op for collection dbname.collection:: caused by :: 
FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: Could not confirm non-existence of database \"dbname\" due to inability to query the config server primary :: caused by :: 
FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: could not find host matching read preference { mode: \"primary\" } for set csReplSet" }
```

Comment: It seems that [read preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) is *primary* and there are no available primary nodes in the replica you are querying. You can change read preference to *secondary*, or even *primaryPreferred*. But the solution depends on the version of Java MongoDB Driver you use. Add Java code that throws exception.

Comment: thanx... the primary replica was down.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Read Preference is creating problem in your end.

Please go thru read preference and set which is more appropriate for your application

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/

If your issue is something related to the one which is mentioned in below jira then we need mongo version 3.3.11 and currently we have only [3.2.9 released](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2/?_ga=1.210745873.569872287.1470499008).

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22620

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility of read preference member is not available in replicaset in your case i.e primary not available.

For one or more reason's.

- Failover scenario when newely primary is getting elected.
- Majority of server's not available leaving no primary available.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-sharded-clusters/