# FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: Could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" }

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes-helm

I want to use mongodb-shard for my project. I created a helm chart https://github.com/b-rohit/mongodb-shard-chart to deploy to kubernetes cluster.

I use `kind` cluster running locally to test it. The config and shard servers are running properly. I am able to execute commands in their mongo shells. The mongos server is not able to connect to the replica set in config server. I get following error message in mongos

```
2020-04-17T13:33:31.579+0000 W  SHARDING [replSetDistLockPinger] pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: Could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" } for set mongors1conf
2020-04-17T13:33:31.579+0000 W  SHARDING [mongosMain] Error initializing sharding state, sleeping for 2 seconds and trying again :: caused by :: FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: Error loading clusterID :: caused by :: Could not find host matching read preference { mode: "nearest" } for set mongors1conf
2020-04-17T13:33:31.579+0000 I  SHARDING [shard-registry-reload] Periodic reload of shard registry failed  :: caused by :: FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: could not get updated shard list from config server :: caused by :: Could not find host matching read preference { mode: "nearest" } for set mongors1conf; will retry after 30s
```

On config server logs are following

```
2020-04-17T13:33:11.578+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.244.0.6:34400 #5 (1 connection now open)
2020-04-17T13:33:11.578+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn5] received client metadata from 10.244.0.6:34400 conn5: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceTL", version: "4.2.5" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "18.04" } }
2020-04-17T13:33:11.589+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn5] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local from client 10.244.0.6:34400
2020-04-17T13:33:38.197+0000 I  SHARDING [replSetDistLockPinger] Marking collection config.lockpings as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-04-17T13:33:38.202+0000 W  SHARDING [replSetDistLockPinger] pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: LockStateChangeFailed: findAndModify query predicate didn't match any lock document
2020-04-17T13:44:39.743+0000 I  CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Failed to create config.system.sessions: Cannot create config.system.sessions until there are shards, will try again at the next refresh interval
2020-04-17T13:44:39.743+0000 I  CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions refresh interval: Cannot create config.system.sessions until there are shards
2020-04-17T13:44:39.743+0000 I  SH_REFR  [ConfigServerCatalogCacheLoader-1] Refresh for collection config.system.sessions took 0 ms and found the collection is not sharded
2020-04-17T13:44:39.743+0000 I  CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval: Collection config.system.sessions is not sharded.
2020-04-17T13:44:42.570+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn5] end connection 10.244.0.10:37922 (0 connections now open)
```

I am new to mongodb. It took lot of time to put this chart together. I checked other similar questions also. [could not find host matching read preferences in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117060/could-not-find-host-matching-read-preferences-in-mongodb)

I am not able to debug it further.

Answer (score 3):

Your config server replica set is either:

- not running (not all nodes are up)
- not a replica set (replSetInitiate not executed, or failed)
- is referenced from the shard nodes incorrectly (wrong host, ip or wrong replica set name)
- is up and running but your shards aren't allowed to access it due to firewall rules

Ensure you can access the replica set nodes from `mongo` shell from the machines on which the shard `mongod`s are running.